# How best to deal with a csv file which contains both DOS and unix line encodings

Tags: ruby, csv

Using ruby 2.7.

When parsing a csv file, if that file was created on a unix-ish machine, then edited on a windows machine, we can get a file where line 1 is terminated with `\n`, line 2 is blank and terminated with `\r\n`, and line 3 is also terminated with `\n`.  This results in `CSV::MalformedCSVError (New line must be <"\n"> not <"\r"> in line 2.)`  The input string is UTF-8 encoded.

I'm not finding any luck with the CSV class, so the 2 options I came up with are parsing each line of the csv, which would be a big rewrite, or "fixing" the input stream with something like `gsub()`.

How insane is the following `gsub()` when the input is UTF-8.  Is there a better way to deal with the error?

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'csv'
=> false
irb(main):002:0> csv="name,value\n\r\nid,1"
irb(main):003:0> CSV::parse(csv)
Traceback (most recent call last):
       16: from /usr/local/bin/irb:23:in `<top (required)>'
       15: from /usr/local/bin/irb:23:in `load'
       14: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.3/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
       13: from (irb):3
       12: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/csv.rb:686:in `parse'
       11: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/csv.rb:1289:in `read'
       10: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/csv.rb:1289:in `to_a'
        9: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/csv.rb:1280:in `each'
        8: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/csv.rb:1280:in `each'
        7: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/csv/parser.rb:336:in `parse'
        6: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/csv/parser.rb:823:in `parse_quotable_loose'
        5: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/csv/parser.rb:49:in `each_line'
        4: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/csv/parser.rb:49:in `each_line'
        3: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/csv/parser.rb:52:in `block in each_line'
        2: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/csv/parser.rb:842:in `block in parse_quotable_loose'
        1: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/csv/parser.rb:928:in `parse_quotable_robust'
CSV::MalformedCSVError (New line must be <"\n"> not <"\r"> in line 2.)
irb(main):004:0> CSV::parse(csv.gsub(/\r\n/, "\n"))
=> [["name", "value"], [], ["id", "1"]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the string class has a helper function for this, `String#encode`.

```
irb(main):013:0> csv="name,value\n\r\nid,1"
irb(main):014:0> csv.encode(universal_newline: true)
=> "name,value\n\nid,1"
irb(main):015:0> CSV::parse(csv.encode(universal_newline: true))
=> [["name", "value"], [], ["id", "1"]]
irb(main):016:0> csv="name,value\n\r\nid,1\r\n\n\nfoo,bar\n\r\n\r\nwibble,42"
irb(main):017:0> CSV::parse(csv.encode(universal_newline: true))
=> [["name", "value"], [], ["id", "1"], [], [], ["foo", "bar"], [], [], ["wibble", "42"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Before parsing the file with Ruby, use [`dos2unix`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/) utility on the file to convert all line endings to `\n`.

Comment: ...or `File.write(outfile_name, File.read(infile_name).gsub(/\r/, ''))`?